# Hardhat: setPrevRandao does not work

Tags: hardhat, opcode

I'm trying to simulate `prevrandao` but it does not work out.

To check it, I've written a contract and a test.

**contracts/AnotherContract.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract AnotherContract {
  constructor() {
  }

  function asm() view public returns(uint val) {
    assembly {
      val := prevrandao()
    }
  }
}
```

**test/AnotherContract.ts**

```
import { time, loadFixture, setPrevRandao } from '@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { ethers } from 'hardhat';

describe('AnotherContract', function() {
  async function deployAnotherContract() {

    const AnotherContract = await ethers.getContractFactory('AnotherContract');
    const anotherContract = await AnotherContract.deploy();

    return {anotherContract};
  }

  describe('Deployment', function() {
    it('just it', async function() {
      const {anotherContract} = await loadFixture(deployAnotherContract);
      await setPrevRandao(ethers.BigNumber.from(0));

      expect(await anotherContract.asm()).to.equal(ethers.BigNumber.from(0));
    });
  });
});
```

Despite the fact that I have requested `setPrevRandao` to set it to be 0, it seems to be different. On top of that, it never changes:

```
1) AnotherContract
       Deployment
         just it:

      AssertionError: expected 110809542029779650567079838414844525958699392492796959957735648389144806727954 to equal 0. The numerical values of the given "ethers.BigNumber" and "ethers.BigNumber" inputs were compared, and they differed.
      + expected - actual

      -110809542029779650567079838414844525958699392492796959957735648389144806727954
      +0
```